# What switch and relay circuitry is required to manage two water well pumps effectively?

Tags: water, pump, relay

Here is my dilemma. I have two water wells; consequently, I have two deep well pumps. Presently I have a relay set up to switch wells each time the pressure switch requires water. They are labeled #1 and #2. #1 is the shallower well and will run out of water if demand is high (such as irrigating garden or lawn). This causes the pressure switch to shut off the pumps to keep them from operating dry.
I would like to set up my system to run #2, #2, #2, #2, #2, #1, but have no idea what kind of switching is required.      Any ideas??

Comment: Do you want some sort of staged control for the two well pumps, where the second comes on if the first isn't keeping the pressure up? Or are you really wanting the second pump to carry 5/6ths of the load?

Comment: Do you need to use the shallow well or are you using it to save $?

Comment: i want second pump to carry 5/6th of the load

Comment: I need to use both wells

Comment: would one quarter or one eighth for pump 1 and the rest for pump 2 be close enough ?

Comment: Do you want pump #1 to run 1/6th of the total run time, or to run 1 in every 6 times the pressure switch calls for water?

Comment: To batsplatsterson ---- looking for 1 of 6 pressure switch calls. This would give well #1 enough time to regenerate itself. #1 has enough H20, just slow at regeneration.When it is depleted it takes about 8 hours to reach its static level.

Comment: To Jasen---- I would prefer 1/8.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with four special purpose relays.  Relays are basically electrically operated switches.  Alternating relays are special relays that cycle between two or more loads sequentially when they are electrically activated.

You could cascade one triplex alternating relay with three regular (duplex) alternating relays to achieve what you want - calling pump #1 every sixth call.

The pressure switch that calls the pump would energize the coil of the triplex alternating relay.  Each of the three outputs of the alternating relay would go to a duplex alternating relay.

Each of the three duplex relays has two outputs for a total of six outputs.  You'd wire one of the outputs to start pump #1, the rest all to start pump #2.  This is what would be energized each consecutive call for water from the pressure switch-

First call:
Output 1 of triplex, Output 1 of duplex A

Second call:
Output 2 of triplex, Output 1 of duplex B

Third  call:
Output 3 of triplex, Output 1 of duplex C

Fourth call:
Output 1 of triplex, Output 2 of duplex A

Fifth call:
Output 2 of triplex, Output 2 of duplex B

Sixth  call:
Output 3 of triplex, Output 2 of duplex C

and at that point the cycle repeats.  So if Pump #1 is connected to say Output 2 of Duplex C, and Pump #2 is wired to the rest, Pump #1 will run every sixth call.

See Macromatic ARP and ATP models for an example.  This may be $300.00 or so of relays - a PLC would actually be cheaper.  The relays would be very simple.

Then again if you change your mind and you want pump #1 to run 1/7th of the time, with the PLC that's an easy programming change, with the relays you are S. O. L.

---

*Original answer...

> I am assuming you have a "flip flop" relay or alternating relay
>   currently wired to alternate pump 1 and pump 2.   If there was such a
>   thing as a six way alternating relay, that would be perfect for you,
>   that might work - you could connect five sets of contacts to pump 1
>   and one set to pump 2.  But I don't think such a relay is available.
>
> The best solution is probably a programmable relay, available from a
>   variety of vendors, or a small PLC.  However there is some learning
>   curve involved with either of these options.*

Comment: Thanks batsplatsterson,      Got me thinking (and calling around)   Looks like a Macromatic TR-6512U time delay relay will solve my problem. I will just limit the run-time of well #1 on each cycle, and continue to operate them "flipflop" fashion!

Comment: @77yosk8r -- post your setup as an answer and I'll give it a +1

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and came up with this idea. Why not limit the amount of water you pump from the shallow well? I then GOOGLED "water flow limiter for a well" and came up with many companies and products The "DOLE" name looked promising. I never bought any of these but the construction looks simple.  You could call the companies, explain your problem and ask for their direction.  and for their recommendations.( I lived on well water for most of my life and was always coming up with ideas). This may work for you. Install a "flow limiter" so you will always use the low flow well but limit the amount taken from that well. You could set the shallow well pump to start first and the other well pump to run when needed. This will insure that the low flow well is used but will not exceed it's capacity.